# how can I make sense of the trigonometric outputs of radian values that are not represented as multiples of π?

Tags: trigonometry

E.g., $\cos 2, \cos3$ are negative. Is there a conversion formula?

Comment: Sure. Divide the argument (i.e., your $2$ or $3$) by $\pi$ and round to the nearest integer. If the result is even/odd, then the cosine is positive/negative. - $\frac 2\pi$ and $\frac 3\pi$ are both $\approx 1$, so $\cos 2$ and $\cos 3$ are negative

Comment: I think there may be a conceptual mistake happening here. In $\cos 2 \approx -0.42$, the $2$ *is a radian measure*. I think your question is actually, "how can I make sense of the trigonometric outputs of radian values that are not represented as multiples of $\pi$?"

Comment: @zahbaz, yup...and guess what I just changed my question to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\dfrac{\pi}2 \; \leq 2\;\leq 3\leq \;\pi$$ (Think second quadrant.) So yes, in radians, $\cos 2$, and $\cos 3$ are negative.

(Radians are the default measure of angles, and in most cases, barring the designation of angle x in degrees, like $(x^\circ)$, they are assumed to be measured in radians.)

In degrees, we have $2 \times \frac{180^\circ}{\pi} $ degrees.

Similarly for converting $3$ radians to degrees.

Answer (score 2):

When you write $\cos(a)$, without any precision, it means that $a$ is in radian.

if $a$ is in degree, you must indicate it.

$\cos(2)$ with $2$ in radian is $<0$ cause $\frac{\pi}{2}<2 rad<\pi$.